# How to set an Entity to only accept specific values for byte type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

```
public byte? Sex { get; set; }
```

I want only 1 and 0 to be accepted in this field. How should I approach this?

I have tried to use `IValidateObject` to solve this, but it didn't work.

Comment: Write a setter method that accepts 0 and 1 and throws an InvalidArgumentException otherwise?

Comment: *"specific values for {byte} type"* in C# this is called `enum` type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
public class Person
{
    private byte? _sex;
    public byte? Sex
    {
        get { return _sex; }
        set { _sex = value == 0 || value == 1 ? value : null; }
    }
}
```

or if you are using DataAnnotations

```
public class Person
{
    [Range(0, 1,
    ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be  {1} or {2}.")]
    public byte? Sex {get; set;}
}
```

test

```
var p = new Person();

var vc = new ValidationContext (p);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
p.Sex = 5;
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(p,vc,results ,true);

if(!isValid)
foreach (var res in results)
    Console.WriteLine(res.ErrorMessage);
```

output

```
Value for Sex must be  0 or 1.
```